# Wordpress loop start from third post

Tags: php, wordpress

I searched a lot but I didn't get exact answer, I want my Wordpress loop to start selecting two posts from third post in the recent posts order by category like "news". How can I do it?
just like in SQL I think

```
SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY date DESC  LIMIT 2,2;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try below code:

```
query_posts('offset=2&posts_per_page=2&cat=<id_of_cat>');
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    endwhile;
```

Hope it helps.